# How to update a variable in an ISR using Timers

Tags: arduino-mega, interrupt, timers, variables, isr

I'm trying to check the frequency of Timer3 using a counter. The value of the counter, declared as volatile, is incremented in the ISR and every second the sum is shown in the main loop and the value reset to zero.

The timer has been set up correctly. (If I choose a 3Hz timer I can see the led blinking)

**The problem**

The counter isn't incremented. Here is the output:

```
Setup Completed
tick: 1
tick: 0
tick: 0
tick: 0
```

**CODE**

```
volatile int cont = 0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

  // Initialize Timer
  cli();          // disable global interrupts
  TCCR3A = 0;     // set entire TCCR3A register to 0
  TCCR3B = 0;     // same for TCCR3B

  // set compare match register to desired timer count: 800 Hz
  OCR3B = 20; // 800Hz 5; // 3 Hz
  // turn on CTC mode:
  TCCR3B |= (1 << WGM12);
  // Set CS10 and CS12 bits for 1024 prescaler:
  TCCR3B |= (1 << CS30) | (1 << CS32);
  // enable timer compare interrupt:
  TIMSK3 |= (1 << OCIE3B);
  // enable global interrupts:
  sei();

  Serial.println("Setup completed");
}

void loop()
{
  if (millis() % 1000 == 0)
  {
    Serial.print(" tick: ");
    Serial.println(cont);
    cont = 0;
  }
}

ISR(TIMER3_COMPB_vect)
{
  //digitalWrite(13, digitalRead(13) ^ 1);
  cont++;
}
```

**EDIT**
This timer is used to read an anlog value from an accelerometer and store it in an array of float. But at the moment I'm stuck on this update issue.

**SOLUTION 1**
Thanks to Gerben

```
volatile int cont = 0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

  // Initialize Timer
  cli();          // disable global interrupts
  TCCR3A = 0;     // set entire TCCR3A register to 0
  TCCR3B = 0;     // same for TCCR3B

  // set compare match register to desired timer count: 800 Hz
  OCR3A = 20; // 20; //800Hz 5; // 3 Hz
  // turn on CTC mode:
  TCCR3B |= (1 << WGM32);
  // Set CS10 and CS12 bits for 1024 prescaler:
  TCCR3B |= (1 << CS30) | (1 << CS32);
  // enable timer compare interrupt:
  TIMSK3 |= (1 << OCIE3B);
  // enable global interrupts:
  sei();
  Serial.println("Setup completed");
}

void loop()
{
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println(cont);
  cont = 0;
}

ISR(TIMER3_COMPB_vect)
{
  cont++;
}
```

**SOLUTION 2**
Thanks to BrettM

```
volatile int cont = 0;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

  // Initialize Timer
  cli();          // disable global interrupts
  TCCR3A = 0;     // set entire TCCR3A register to 0
  TCCR3B = 0;     // same for TCCR3B

  // set compare match register to desired timer count: 800 Hz
  OCR3B =  20; //800Hz 5; // 3 Hz
  // turn on CTC mode:
  //TCCR3B |= (1 << WGM32);
  // Set CS10 and CS12 bits for 1024 prescaler:
  TCCR3B |= (1 << CS30) | (1 << CS32);
  // enable timer compare interrupt:
  TIMSK3 |= (1 << OCIE3B);
  // enable global interrupts:
  sei();
  Serial.println("Setup completed");
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println(cont); 
  cont = 0;
  delay(1000);

}

ISR(TIMER3_COMPB_vect)
{
  TCNT3 = 0;
  cont++;
}
```

Comment: And if you uncomment the `digitalWrite` line you see the LED blink about once per second (every 0.66s)?

Comment: Yes, If I uncomment `digitalWrite` and set `OCR3B = 5;` the led blinks at approximately that frequency.

Comment: Then it's a mistery. Have you tried commenting out the `cont = 0;` inside the loop? What happens then?

Comment: Also, the output you provided doesn't match the code, as each line should be "`tick: 0`" instead of just "`0`".

Comment: Yes I've updated the text with the output I get. Now there is a 1! XD

Comment: Try increasing the frequency. I think your if statement may be clearing the counter more often than the interrupt is called, somehow. But then you should see more ones in the output. Also let if run for longer (say 1 minute) and paste the results. Also, when you update the question, leave the old output so your question makes sense (without the edit history).

Comment: I've set OCR3B to 20 (800 Hz, prescaler 1024 -> 800Hz right?) and commented the line cont = 0 in the if statement. The output in the EDIT2

Comment: Can't see the EDIT2. Did you really save it?

Comment: Yes, I've tried printing the value every 5, 20 and 50 sec. The count's value doesn't change.

Comment: I suspect that the interrupt routine is being called only once and then it is disabled. I've read somewhere that the interrupts are disabled when an interrupt code is running, and in some cases you have to re-enable it, but I'm really not sure if that's the case. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable will come to our rescue...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In CTC mode the top is `OCR3A`, not `OCR3B`!

After that `TIMSK3 |= (1 << OCIE3B);` should also be changed to `TIMSK3 |= (1 << OCIE3A);`, and `ISR(TIMER3_COMPB_vect)` to `ISR(TIMER3_COMPA_vect)`

For 3Hz, `OCR3A` should be 5208, not 20.

Technically `TCCR3B |= (1 << WGM12);` should be `TCCR3B |= (1 << WGM32);`

Comment: With your configuration the counter is not updated and every second the "Setup completed" sentence, (written in the setup() function!) is shown. Really weird behaviour.

Comment: Solved using `TIMSK3 |= (1 << OCIE3B);`. Thank you Gerben! Please modify your answer and I'll accept it as solution.

Comment: I forgot the mention you also need the change the ISR vector. `ISR(TIMER3_COMPB_vect)` should be `ISR(TIMER3_COMPA_vect)`. If an ISR isn't defined, the AVR will reset itself, like you were experiencing. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 3):

It seems my answer to [this question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/5396/setting-timer3-in-ctc-mode-conflict-with-servo-library/5432#5432) was previously incomplete, thanks for pointing out that CTC mode only works with OCR3A Gerben. I apologize for not testing an answer before I post it.

Given the information only in this question Gerben's answer is complete, but since your other question implies that you cannot use OCR3A due to the Servo library I'll add a bit. (I've also edited that answer)

you can emulate the behavior of CTC mode by setting TCNT3 to 0 in your interrupt routine. Remember to remove the line that turns on CTC mode in your code.

I've tested your code with this ISR:

```
ISR(TIMER3_COMPB_vect)
{
  TCNT3 = 0;
  cont++;
}
```

and this configuration of the timer registers

```
OCR3B = 5208; // 800Hz 5; // 3 Hz
// Set CS10 and CS12 bits for 1024 prescaler:
TCCR3B |= (1 << CS30) | (1 << CS32);
// enable timer compare interrupt:
TIMSK3 |= (1 << OCIE3B);
```

This might be a bit less accurate at high frequencies than CTC, I'm not sure, but at 3Hz it worked perfectly. Notice that 5208 was the correct OCR value, not 20 (again thanks to Gerben).

Comment: I've tried your code but the counter isn't incremented. I've added the `TCNT3=0;` in the ISR() and removed 
 `//TCCR3B |= (1 << WGM32);` in the setup() as you said. I've also tried commenting out the `cont=0;` line but nothing changed

Comment: Make sure the code matches what is posted in the question in every other way. Try changing your loop to just `println(cont); delay(1000);`. Also you are still including the bits with cli() and TCCR3A etc correct?

Comment: Ok thanks. At 800 Hz is still accurate!