# Setting the frequency of a timer interrupt

Tags: arduino-mega, interrupt, timers, sound

**The concept:**

Play a sine wave saved as a character array in PROGMEM through an 8-bit DAC connected to the PORTC pins on the Arduino Mega.

**This works:**

```c++
// File just defines an array and a size

#include "sine440.h"

int i = 0;
void setup() {
  DDRC = B11111111;
}

void loop() {
  PORTC = pgm_read_byte(&sine[i++]);
  if(i >= sine_size){
    i = i - sine_size;
  }

  delayMicroseconds(60);
}
```

The above code produces a sine wave of about 440 Hz, exactly what I wanted. Now, I'd like to move this into an interrupt routine, as follows:

#### This doesn't work

```c++
#include "sine440.h"

int i = 0;
void setup() {
  DDRC = B11111111;
  TCCR5B = (1 << WGM52) | (1 << CS50 );
  OCR5A =  16000000/16000;
  TIMSK5 = (1 << OCIE5A);
}

ISR(TIMER5_COMPA_vect){
  PORTC = pgm_read_byte(&sine[i++]);
  if(i >= sine_size){
    i = i - sine_size;
  }
}

void loop() {

}
```

The above code produces a sine wave of 1721 Hz. I know that this means it's iterating through the array too fast, but I don't know how to change it. In order for it to produce 440 Hz, it needs to be preforming 16,000 iterations per second, which is what I believe  `OCR5A =  16000000/16000;` does. **But** it doesn't appear that changing the value of OCR5A does anything at all. Giving it the max value of 65,535 still produces a 1721 Hz sine wave...

So what am I doing wrong here? How do I change the speed of this timer interrupt?

Comment: Try setting `TCCR5A = 0` explicitly, maybe arduino has WGM51 or WGM50 set at startup for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I second BrettAM's comment. The Arduino IDE sets most of all the timers up for PWM, and I had to comment out a section once to use my own ISR with Timer 3 on a 32u4, because no matter where or how I set it, the CTC interrupt never went. The `WGM50` and `CS51` are set at the start of the Arduino files basically, so that messes with your settings.

You will need go into the Arduino core files. This is `$install_path/arduino-1.x.x/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/`, and under that directory you need to find file `wiring.c`. This file contains all the setup of the timers for PWM and the `millis()` or `micros()` functions.

Go to line 342. Located there is this:

```cpp
#if defined(TCCR5B) && defined(CS51) && defined(WGM50)

  sbi(TCCR5B, CS51);           //set ter 5 prescale factor to 64
  sbi(TCCR5B, CS50);
  sbi(TCCR5A, WGM50);         // put timer 5 in 8-bit phase correct pwm mode

#endif
```

Here you can place another `#if defined()` macro around this, resulting in:

```cpp
#if !defined(doNotSetTimer5)

  #if defined(TCCR5B) && defined(CS51) && defined(WGM50)

    sbi(TCCR5B, CS51);           //set ter 5 prescale factor to 64
    sbi(TCCR5B, CS50);
    sbi(TCCR5A, WGM50);         // put timer 5 in 8-bit phase correct pwm mode

  #endif

#endif
```

Now when you want to use your custom settings, you will put the following at the top of your .ino file:

```cpp
#define doNotSetTimer5
#include <wiring.c>
```

That does not block the Arduino environment from setting up Timer 5 when compiled with other code, but only when you want to use custom settings (changed because of @Gerben's suggestion). When you change these settings you will lose PWM on 3 pins: `44 45 46`. But you will be able to make use of setting your own PWM up or a CTC `ISR()`.

This doesn't mess with anything else and is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a `!defined(...)`, as to not break existing code? Something like `#if !defined(doNotSetTimer5)`. That way you need to set the flag only if you want the no-standard settings.

Comment: @Gerben         that's a good point, I will change it to that rather then. Will be more compatible with stuff. +1

Comment: Hey, thanks. I actually found a thread yesterday before seeing BretAm's comment that addressed this issue with a different timer. So i tried it out and it worked. But this did a great job in explaining WHY it was happening.

Comment: @Dave          pleasure, maybe just add that link as a comment here or something to have another way too.